# Remove input and buttons by button function

Tags: javascript, function

With a loop, I´m creating some inputs and buttons. One button is a remove button. If I press the remove button, I want to remove all inputs and buttons with that loop.

So e.g. if I press the third remove button, all of the created elements in the third loop run should be removed.

My function for that button isn´t working. Can someone help me out and tell/show me what I have to change in my code in order for it to work?

Thank you and Kind Regards

This is a part of my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayinput.length; i++){
    
    // example input
            var myParent1 = InputContainer;
            var numberfield = document.createElement("input");
            numberfield.setAttribute('class','InputNew');
            numberfield.setAttribute('id','InputNew-' + i);
            numberfield.setAttribute('value','0');      
            myParent1.appendChild(numberfield); 
            
    //example button
            var myParent2 = AddContainer;
            var addierenButton = document.createElement("button");
            addierenButton.setAttribute('class','addButton');
            addierenButton.textContent = "+";
            addierenButton.id = "add_btn_" + i;
            addierenButton.setAttribute('onclick','add(this)');
            myParent.appendChild(addButton);
            
    //remove button
            var myParent3 = RemoveContainer;
            var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
            removeButton.setAttribute('class','removeButton');
            removeButton.id = "remove_btn_" + i;
            removeButton.textContent = "X";
            removeButton.setAttribute('onclick','remove(this)');
            myParent3.appendChild(removeButton);

};
            
function remove(btn){
        const num = btn.id.replace("remove_btn_", "");
        
        var delInput= document.getElementById("InputNew-" + num);
        var delAdd= document.getElementById("add_btn_" + num);
        var delRemove= document.getElementById("remove_btn_" + num);
        
            delInput.remove();
            delAdd.remove();
            delRemove.remove();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code logic is good but you had a few syntax errors.

### Try the following snippet

```js
const arrayinput = [0, 1, 2];

window.onload = (event) => {

  for(var i = 0; i < arrayinput.length; i++){

    // example input
    var myParent1 = document.getElementById('root');
    var numberfield = document.createElement("input");
    numberfield.setAttribute('class','InputNew');
    numberfield.setAttribute('id','InputNew-' + i);
    numberfield.setAttribute('value','0');      
    myParent1.appendChild(numberfield); 

    //example button
    var myParent2 = document.getElementById('root');
    var addButton = document.createElement("button");
    addButton.setAttribute('class','addButton');
    addButton.textContent = "+";
    addButton.id = "add_btn_" + i;
    addButton.setAttribute('onclick','add(this)');
    myParent2.appendChild(addButton);

    //remove button
    var myParent3 = document.getElementById('root');
    var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
    removeButton.setAttribute('class','removeButton');
    removeButton.id = "remove_btn_" + i;
    removeButton.textContent = "X";
    removeButton.setAttribute('onclick','remove(this)');
    myParent3.appendChild(removeButton);

  }
}
            
function remove(btn){
        const num = btn.id.replace("remove_btn_", "");
        
        var delInput= document.getElementById("InputNew-" + num);
        var delAdd= document.getElementById("add_btn_" + num);
        var delRemove= document.getElementById("remove_btn_" + num);
        
            delInput.remove();
            delAdd.remove();
            delRemove.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```